# Photovoltaic amp

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis, analog, gain, transimpedance

I am trying to make a transimpedance amp and it's not working right. The signal going in has 167 Hz and also it's 20 uA.

It is acting as a low pass filter and according to the equation I use, the cutting frequency is 1756 Hz. I think it should work.

I used this equation to get the voltage I want which is very close to 2V. (12-Vout)/0.5M=20uA. The output will be 1.

I still don't see any result. Nothing at all. I don't know what is wrong with my design. I really appreciate your help and I am just a newbie so please be patient with me. Thank you.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQM1Yk.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Ditch V1 and tie + input to ground

Comment: Then, I will be getting 20Vs which I don't want. I want 1V maximum @JImDearden Thank you though.

Comment: You can't get 20V out, you only have a 12V supply, besides your circuit doesn't work.  As Tony (also) points out in his answer let V(in)+ = 0V.  Once you **have a signal at the output** you can shift it up or down.  The voltage offset to V(in)+ is used when you have a single power supply. You are using a dual supply.

Comment: Try flipping the photodiode.. I think you've got current flowing the wrong way.  (and reduce V1 some... as per Tony)

Comment: @GeorgeHerold Flipping it and removing the bias voltage is changing to photovoltaic mode.. usually not desirable.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany,  Hmm OK.  I may not be understanding the circuit.  I thought the intent of the voltage on the non-inverting input was to increase the range of the output... 20uA x 1 Meg= 20V.  (And as long a speed is not important photovoltaic is mode is fine... well.. low power too.. biasing increases the saturation current/ light level.)

Comment: @GeorgeHerold I see a reverse biased PD with 20uA 'dark' current and I think he wants to **decrease** the range of the output (offset so the gain can be cranked up) so 20uA is 0V out and 22uA is 2V out. Of course, my assumptions could well be out for a mid-day meal.

Answer (score 1):

Datasheet says *"The amplifier will operate with a common-mode input voltage equal to the positive supply; however, the gain bandwidth and slew rate may be decreased in this condition"*

However if Vin(+) = Vcc and we know Vin+=Vin- in linear opeartion
and we know the Pd rises in voltage with current, it will be above Vcc and not work.

Therefore  Vin(+) must be well below Vcc not at least 3V above Vee. 
So let Vin(+) = 0V and use another inverting gain amp for 2nd stage if you want positive outputs.

Comment: I am using OPA 551 so do you think it will work with that too? Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Connect the PD anode to -12 rather than to ground, and ground the non-inverting op-amp input.

That will give you a bias voltage on the PD of -12V and an output dark voltage near 0V, going positive for more light intensity. I am assuming, of course, that your intention is to operate the photodiode in the photoconductive mode rather than photovoltaic mode.

Note that for a practical circuit you may need to filter the PD bias voltage.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fedsIw.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

You can level shift the signal downward if you want to by connecting a resistor from the inverting input to a positive reference. If you want the output to be 1V at 20uA PD current you need to supply 19uA so a resistor of 12V/19uA ~= 632K will do it.